# After a טמא מת gets הזאות and is still טמא until טבילה והערב שמש, is this a new טומאה or the remains of the original טומאה?

Tags: halacha-theory, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, lomdus

Are the הזאות really מטהר him completely, only now is חל a completely new טומאה? Or is this טומאה that he still has the remainder of the old טומאה; the הזאות aren't מטהר him completely and leave over this remaining טומאה until טבילה והערב שמש.

I have some ראיות and נ"מ on this, was wondering if anyone had any more for me.

A possible nafka mina in this chakira is if someone who touches this person who was tamei mes and then had hazah done to him, is it considered tamei mes for the din of tumah hutra btzibur where the halacha is that only tamei mes is hutra btzibur (see gvuras ari Yuma 14a d”h lmaze umazin alav tahor vnogeah tamei). If the old tumah of tumas mes is still there, then we would say tumah hutra btzibur, but if it’s a new tumah, maybe not.

With this chakira perhaps we can also answer the question of the Chavatzeles Hasharon on Tosfos in chulin 11a (d”h מנא). Tosfos says that the chezkas tumah of the gavra is misnaged to the tahara of the mei chatas (and therefore says that the parah is a treifa). The Chavatzeles Hasharon asks, why is it misnaged to the hechsher of the mei chatas, the hazah isn’t metaher the gavra until tvila, so the chezkas tumah shouldn’t be soser that.
According to the tzad in our chakira that the hazah is metaher him legamri it’s possible that this kasha is answered, the tahara of the hazah is indeed misnaged to the tumah of the gavra.

Comment: The tumeat tvul yom is a residual part of the tumeat met. Helachikally many dinim of tumea disappeared an a few remained. The chezkat tumea remains, the din of hutra betsibbur too. Svara pshuta licheora

Comment: Seems bizarre that THB"Z would be more chamur after haza'ah?

Comment: Rambam Biat Mikdash 4:14 and Korban Pesach 6:2